# MongoDB create date get month issue?

Tags: mongodb

Can someone please shed some light on why when I create a date object I receive the wrong month like so:

```
new Date("2013-11-25").getMonth()

output> 10

new Date("2013-11-25").toISOString()

output> 2013-11-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

I've seen this happen a couple of times and it's confusing me slightly. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct. This happens because in javascript month start from 0 not 1.

You can read in details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp).